# compareTo() with generic type

Tags: java, generics, generic-programming

I have defined an array which can hold element of generic type. Now I am comparing the array[index] with another comparable element. Below is the code snippet.

I have defined an array which can hold element of generic type. Now I am comparing the array[index] with another comparable element. Below is the code snippet.

```
public class Test {
    void methodArr(){
        final Comparable[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        Integer item = 10;

        compare(arr, item);
    }


    private int compare(Comparable<?>[] arr, Comparable<?> item) {
        return arr[0].compareTo(item);   //Error in this line
    }
}
```

Now it gives the error in the method compare() at

> arr[0].compareTo(item)

And the error is:

> The method compareTo(capture#1-of ?) in the type
>   comparable is not applicable for the arguments
>   (Comparable)

I don't understand where am I making mistake? My object is the method compare() should take an array as element of type comparable.

Comment: `I have defined an array which can hold element of generic type` could you please show how did you manage that?

Comment: Do all the items have a compareTo with a generic as argument?

Comment: @Everv0id I have declared an array of Integer type which is Comparable object. You can see in the method methodArr().

Comment: That's not a generic type - `Integer` is very much concrete.  You've got a `Comparable[]` due to the fact that arrays are covariant (that is, because an `Integer` is a `Comparable`, an `Integer[]` is a `Comparable[]`).

Comment: If you declare an array of `Integer`, you will get only an array of integers, not `array which can hold element of generic type`.

Comment: Sorry, just edited to make the array Comparable<?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Comparable<?>` means that you don't know what kind of `Comparable` you're getting; you could be getting `Comparable<Object>`, which doesn't work unless you explicitly override `compareTo` for *that* instance of `Object`.

The correct solution to this is to introduce a type parameter to the method such that the type you care about is bound to `Comparable`.

```
private <T extends Comparable<T>> int compare(T[] arr, T item) {
    return arr[0].compareTo(item);
}
```

The above will still work with a `Comparable[]`, not a `Comparable<?>[]`.  Generics and arrays don't mix very well, so where you can, try to avoid combining the two.

If you want to avoid the unchecked warnings (which at this point can be safely ignored due to array covariance),then you would modify the signature of your `methodArr` method to accept a similar bound.

```
<T extends Comparable<T>> void methodArr(final T[] arr, T item) {
    // use the passed-in arr and item variables instead.
}
```

Comment: Thanks Makoto. Sorry for making all confused. I had to declare the array of generic type which can hold any comparable object. I just edited the question. Please help me what could be the solution.

Comment: The above solution worked when the array is of type Integer. But after making the array of type Comparable<?>[], it gives error while calling the method compare() in methodArr().

Comment: Refresh the answer.  You really shouldn't be bothering with `Comparable<?>[]`.  You don't care what type the `Comparable` array is bound to so long as it's a `Comparable`.  So simply disregard the generification of it.

Comment: did you mean it should be Comparable[] arr instead Comparable<?>[] arr? If yes then there is warning for using Comparable raw type.

Answer (score 1):

There is no relationship between the two wildcards in your parameters. Instead you should specify that they are the same type using an explicit type variable:

```
private <T extends Comparable<T>> int compare(T[] arr, T item) {
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple

```
private <T extends Comparable>  int compare(T[] arr, T item) {
        return arr[0].compareTo(item);   
    }
```

Comment: `<T extends Comparable>` introduces a raw type bound on `T` and results in an unchecked warning from the compiler, which is what we want to avoid.